# Sample intersections in Open Street Map

Tags: algorithm, openstreetmap

I have calculated all the intersections in Manhattan using the data from OpenStreet Map. Every intersection is basically a latitude longitude tuple. For example : **{-122.1808293, 37.4506505}**.

There are more than 100K of such records. But i need to sample just 200 of those intersections which are distributed across Manhattan. According to Google the area of Manhattan is 22.8 mi² which means that i need to select intersections that are on an average 0.114 mi away from each other.

Any pointers as to how i can approach this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: K-means clustering with K = 200 clusters?

Comment: ... on average 0,114 mi² per sample. average distance to nearest neighbours depends on the grid type.